# How do I analyze a PCRE pattern?

Tags: c++, performance, pcre

I need a performance analysis of a PCRE pattern for both time and memory.
Some parameters like the ones below are extracted from pattern using `pcre_fullinfo` and `pcre_exec` functions.

- Size of compiled pattern
- Number of the highest back reference
- Number of capturing subpatterns
- Number of named subpatterns
- Time of match finding in a random buffer

Now the question is are these parameters enough or are there others that I can use for better analysis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hamed, unearthing this ancient question because it's a good one and I see that you're still active on SO.

As it turns out, PCRE ships out with a very useful test utility called pcretest. Among other things, it lets you trace the path of the engine as it tries to match strings, and it lets you specify a number of runs.

If you're on Unix or OSX, you'll have to compile pcretest by following the download link on [pcre.org](http://www.pcre.org/). The package had everything you need to make the file. If you're on Windows, the [pcre.org](http://www.pcre.org/) front page tells you where to get the latest pcretest binary, along with a Windows pcregrep binary, also part of the pcre test suite.

The list of options is quite long.

1. For an overview in the console, type `pcretest --help`
2. For "getting started" usage, read the page that offers the
   Windows binaries (see above)
3. For full directions, see the [official pcretest documentation](http://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/exim-doc-4.63/html/doc/pcretest.html).